# Getting attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0" after install

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, grubrescue

After installing 20.04 I keep getting the error message attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0" Entering rescue mode...

I have done a lot of reading on this and have tried all of the given solutions and none of them have worked.  I have even loaded the Ubuntu LiveCd and run the Boot Rescue program and I still get the error.

The machine is a Dell R710 with a H700 Raid Controller with six 3TB HDDs in a Raid 50 configuration and I'm using all but ~500MB.

I also know that this is an Ubuntu install issue as I can load Windows 10 and have absolutely no errors.  I have also tried installing 14.xx and I get the same error.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue.

Machine was not set to UEFI but was in BIOS.

Changed setting and all is working now.